# AJAX <select> values wrong (sometimes)

Tags: php, ajax

I'm having an issue with a piece of Ajax code (i'm not too familiar with ajax) someone else wrote the Ajax code which does and doesn't work:

```
<?php

include('includes/db_connection.php');
include('includes/sessions.php');
include('includes/functions.php');
include('includes/header.php');
include('includes/navbar-logged.php');
require_once('api-sape.php');
// init sape
$sape        = new SapeApi();
$userId      = $sape->login(SAPE_USER, SAPE_PASS);  
// isset
$siteId = isset($_GET['id']) ? (int)$_GET['id'] : null;
// query this offers details
$siteRow = DB::getInstance()->selectOneByField('sites', 'site_id', $siteId);
// get the logged in users id
$r = get_logged_in_users_details($member);
// the ID
$hID = $r['member_id'];
// paid?
if ($user['member_fees_paid'] == 0){
    stderr('Only subscribed users can buy links! you can <a href="my-account.php">subscribe on your control panel page</a> by clicking the paypal button.');
}
?>
<?php
if (isset($_POST['submitPurchase'])) {
    if ($member == SAPE_USER) { showPre($_POST); }
    // try...
    try {
      // vars
      $pageID     = $_POST['page_id'];
      $urlID      = $_POST['url_id'];
      $memberID   = $_POST['member_id']; 
      $anchorText = $_POST['anchor_text']; 
      $anchorID   = $_POST['anchor_id']; 
      $projID     = $_POST['project_id']; 
      $linkPrice  = $_POST['price'];    
      // buy the link in sape (only if you are admin do they go direct :))
      if ($member == SAPE_USER) { $userBuy = $sape->placement_create($pageID, $urlID, $anchorText); }
      // show var_dump
      if ($member == SAPE_USER) { showPre($userBuy); }
      // insertion (the user still needs to pay first before they go live)
      DB::getInstance()->insert(
            'pending',
        [
            'pending_page_id' => $pageID,
            'pending_url_id' => $urlID,
            'pending_member_id' => $memberID,
            'pending_project_id' => $projID,
            'pending_anchor_id' => $anchorID,
            'pending_text' => $anchorText,
            'pending_price' => $linkPrice,
            'pending_added' => date('Y-m-d H:i:s')
      ]);   
      if ($member == SAPE_USER) {
          // insertion
          DB::getInstance()->insert(
                'purchased',
            [
                'purchased_sape_ref_id' => $userBuy,
                'purchased_member_id' => $memberID,
                'purchased_project_id' => $projID,
                'purchased_anchor_id' => $anchorID,
                'purchased_text' => $anchorText,
                'purchased_price' => $linkPrice,
                'purchased_added' => date('Y-m-d H:i:s')
          ]); 
      }  
      // message      
      stdmsg('Link is queued to go live, checkout on the <a href="links-pending.php">links pending purchase</a> screen.');  
    } catch (SapeApiException $e) {
            stderr($e->getMessage());
    } 
}
?>
<div class="panel panel-primary">
    <div class="panel-heading">URL: <a href="<?php echo $siteRow['site_sape_url']; ?><?php echo $siteRow['site_uri']; ?>" target="_blank"><b><font color="yellow"><?php echo $siteRow['site_sape_url']; ?><?php echo $siteRow['site_uri']; ?></font></b></a></div>
    <div class="panel-body">
    <?php
    $conversion = currencyConverter("RUB", "USD", $siteRow['site_uri_price']);
    ?>
        <form action="" method="post" class="form-horizontal container-fluid" role="form">  
        <table class="table table-condensed table-striped table-hover table-responsive">
            <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>URL ID</th>
                <th>Page ID</th>
                <th>Site Level</th>
                <th>Cost (₽ in Rubles)</th>
                <th>Cost ($ in Dollars)</th>
            </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
             <tr>
                <td><?php echo $siteRow['site_sape_id']; ?></td>
                <td><?php echo $siteRow['site_uri_id']; ?></td>
                <td><?php echo $siteRow['site_level']; ?></td>
                <td><?php echo "₽".$siteRow['site_uri_price']; ?></td>
                <td><?php echo "$".number_format($conversion, 2); ?></td>
             </tr>
            </tbody>
        </table>
        </div>
        <div class="panel-footer">
        <b>Choose a Project:</b><select id="projects" name="project_id" class="form-control" required="required">       
        <?php
            $oneRows = DB::getInstance()->select('SELECT * FROM `projects` WHERE `project_member_id`='.$hID);   
        ?>  
        <?php foreach ($oneRows as $ro1) { ?>
        <option id="<?php echo htmlspecialchars($ro1['project_sape_link_id']) ?>" value="<?php echo htmlspecialchars($ro1['project_sape_id']) ?>"><?php echo htmlspecialchars($ro1['project_name']) ?></option>
        <?php } ?>      
        </select>
        <?php
        // query sape...
        $links = $sape->get_url_anchors($oneRows[0]['project_sape_link_id']);   
        ?>
        <b>Choose the Text that will be posted on the target URL:</b><select id="anchors" name="anchor_id" class="form-control" required="required">
        <?php foreach ($links as $link) { ?>
        <option value="<?php echo htmlspecialchars($link["id"]) ?>"><?php echo htmlspecialchars($link["anchor"]) ?></option>
        <?php } ?>
        <?php
        // page_id is the page or uri of the url/pahe.html etc
        // project_sape_link_id is the id of the site we add in create a project screen.
        ?>
        <input type="hidden" id="url_id" name="url_id" value="<?php echo $oneRows[0]['project_sape_link_id']; ?>" />
        <input type="hidden" id="anchor_text" name="anchor_text" value="<?php echo $links[0]["anchor"]; ?>" />
        </select>
        <br />
        <button type="submit" name="submitPurchase" class="btn btn-default">Buy Link</button>
        <input type="hidden" name="member_id" value="<?php echo $hID; ?>" />
        <input type="hidden" name="page_id" value="<?php echo $siteRow['site_uri_id']; ?>" />
        <input type="hidden" name="price" value="<?php echo $siteRow['site_uri_price']; ?>" />
        </div>
    </div>
    <script>
        jQuery("#projects").on('change',function(){
            var link_id = jQuery("#projects option:selected").attr('id');   
            $("#url_id").val(link_id);
            jQuery.post("ajax-get-anchors.php",{
                linkID:link_id
            }).done(function( data ) {
                $("#anchors").empty();
                var result = jQuery.parseJSON(data);
                for(var i = 0; i < result.length;i++){
                    $("#anchors").append('<option id="'+result[i].id+'">'+result[i].anchor+'</option>');
                }
                $("#anchor_text").val(result[0].anchor);
            });
        });
        jQuery("#anchors").on('change',function(){
            var anchor = jQuery("#anchors option:selected").text();
            $("#anchor_text").val(anchor);
        });     
    </script>
  </form>
</div>
<?php

include('includes/footer.php');
```

ajax-get-anchors.php

```
<?php
  require_once('api-sape.php');
  include('includes/constants.php');
  $sape        = new SapeApi();
  $userId      = $sape->login(SAPE_USER, SAPE_PASS);    
  $siteId = isset($_POST['linkID']) ? (int)$_POST['linkID'] : null;
  // init sape
  $result = $sape->get_url_anchors($siteId);
  echo json_encode($result);
?>
```

There is 2 dropdown boxes, the first one is to select a project id for example "25875657" depending on what project id it is, it will pull strings from an api, it totally depends on what the project id is what strings are returned, then it's a case of hitton a button and all the $_POST data is captured at the top

The problem is, if nothing is selected via the drop downs, and the button is pressed the data is all sent fine, but if the top dropdown selects another project (it does change the strings like it should) it's actually sending the "anchor_text" value in place of the "anchor_id"

example (wrong):

```
array(8) {
  ["project_id"]=>
  string(7) "2598013"
  ["anchor_id"]=>
  string(21) "project2DropDownissue"
  ["url_id"]=>
  string(9) "100719868"
  ["anchor_text"]=>
  string(21) "project2DropDownissue"
  ["submitPurchase"]=>
  string(0) ""
  ["member_id"]=>
  string(1) "1"
  ["page_id"]=>
  string(10) "1638871942"
  ["price"]=>
  string(4) "4.14"
}
```

example (correct):

```
array(8) {
  ["project_id"]=>
  string(7) "2597941"
  ["anchor_id"]=>
  string(10) "2501662973"
  ["url_id"]=>
  string(9) "100717187"
  ["anchor_text"]=>
  string(58) "Create a project, you can use the macro #a#project1#/a# in"
  ["submitPurchase"]=>
  string(0) ""
  ["member_id"]=>
  string(1) "1"
  ["page_id"]=>
  string(10) "1252888864"
  ["price"]=>
  string(4) "0.60"
}
```

In the wrong example, the "anchor_id" is replaced by the "anchor_text" which is messing things up.

I hope that makes sense!

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You're missing the *value* attribute in this block.  I've called it out with a comment and corrected it.

```
   jQuery("#projects").on('change',function(){
        var link_id = jQuery("#projects option:selected").attr('id');   
        $("#url_id").val(link_id);
        jQuery.post("ajax-get-anchors.php",{
            linkID:link_id
        }).done(function( data ) {
            $("#anchors").empty();
            var result = jQuery.parseJSON(data);
            for(var i = 0; i < result.length;i++){
                //Add value attribute here:
                $("#anchors").append('<option id="'+result[i].id+'" value="'+result[i].anchor+'">'+result[i].anchor+'</option>');
            }
            $("#anchor_text").val(result[0].anchor);
        });
    });
```

Also, a cleaner version of that same block would look something like this:

```
$.each(result, function(key, value) {   
    $('#anchors')
    .append($('<option>', { value : key })
    .text(value)); 
});
```

The above removes all of the quote escaping from the HTML string and makes it significantly easier to read.  Good luck!

Comment: Thank you axlj, some folks on here are unbelievable who ever down voted.